# ZK NotifyChange Single record from List not whole List?

Tags: java, zk

I have below code I want to NotiFy only Single item of he List not whole List as if we will NotiFy whole List it will reload data again which is consuming lots of memory and looks ugly.Anyone know Better way to increase performance of application?

```
@Command
public void valueChangedListnerForCombo(
            @BindingParam("Code") Combobox combobox,
            @BindingParam("BeanData") Record record,
            @BindingParam("ColumnName") String columnName) {
    super.valueChangedListnerForCombo(combobox, record, columnName);
    if (!adminNewListModelList.contains(record) && !changedListModel.contains(record)){
        changedListModel.add(record);
        BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, this , "adminListboxViewModel");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit :
You can notifyChange a single object like this :

```
BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, record, "*");
```

Result for your cause : **nothing.**
**Why :** Because you do `add` operation. If it is an `update` of `record` this shall work.

You add the object to a listModel so the listModel is changed and has to been notified.
If you only call the `listmodel` and not your getter from your `viewmodel` you normally have performance gain. (try setting a logger on your getter of the object and see what is all called)

```
BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, changedListModel, "*");
```

Edit 2 :

You have your combobox in your method.
Try doing the following in stead of the `postNotifyChanged`

```
combobox.invalidate();
```

This shall set the combobox correct to the underlying model, what you just changed.

Comment: That i know brother please check my question i have to Notify Single record of a List not whole class or Whole list

Comment: Leave this part or remove this part  changedListModel.add(record);   As changes done in adminNewListModelList and this is used in ZUL  I have to Notify Single record of this List i tried BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, record, "*"); but it wont work if i am doing 
BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, adminNewListModelList , "*"); it is working but i have to Notify Single record not whole List. Any idea we can do this?

Comment: like I said result is nothing when you notifychanged the record. With an add or remove operation of your listmodel you have to do notifyChanged of the listmodel, with an update of a record in the list you can notify the object itself.

Comment: I do not able to understand ? "with an update of a record in the list you can notify the object itself. " Do u want to say I have to notify Whole List? No any other way.

Comment: indeed, for add or remove operation you always need to notify your listmodel. For update of record see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173839/notify-change-of-grid-list-tree-inside-a-grid-list-tree