# Grid with nested template rendering

Tags: grid, zk

I have an object A like this:

```
class A
{
   String name;
   List<B> bList;
}

class B
{
   String name;
}
```

And I want to render this in a ZK Grid so that A elements are rows and B elements are columns. In my Composer I have a `getAList()` method that returns a List of A elements.
So far I have this:

```
<grid id="myGrid" model="@{base$composer.AList}">
      <rows>
                    <template name="model">
                        <row align="center">
                            <cell width="196px">${each.name}</cell>
                            <cell>${each.bList}</cell>
                        </row>
                    </template>
                </rows>

</grid>
```

This renders the name element on the left-most column on my row, and then an additional column printing the `ArrayList.toString()` of my bList ArrayList of objects.

What I want to achieve now is to **declaratively** tell ZK to render each of my B elements contained in bList as a single cell. I have seen [this fiddle](http://www.zkfiddle.org/sample/2rjaqos/4-MVVM-with-nested-template) which does something similar with a listbox, but I have neither a listbox nor a MVVM implementation.

Just to be clear, I now I can do this using a `RowRenderer` and creating each cell programmatically via Java code, but I would like to find a declarative solution. Each cell has different CSS properties and events based on its content so doing it through Java codes kind of creates some high coupling I'm not comfortable with.

So how can I nest two templates to achieve this functionality?

EDIT:
Here's a Fiddle describing what I'm trying to achieve:
http://www.zkfiddle.org/sample/25qpefb/3-Grid-with-template

The idea is that Activity objects should be represented as a cell in the same row each. The bit reading

`<cell>${each.activities}</cell>`

should be replaced with what I want to do. Bear in mind that even in the small sample data you could simply statically reference each activity object with an additional  entry, it could be a variable number of elements, and in real data it's up to ~40 elements.

Comment: Can you provide a working example of your current code?

Comment: Is it MVVM or MVC cause your zul code looks more at MVC then MVVM.
Example of grid in grid in MVVM : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173839/notify-change-of-grid-list-tree-inside-a-grid-list-tree

Comment: @chillworld yes as I said Im using MVC. A grid whithin a grid would probably work but there has to be a way to do what I intend to, right? In the end, it's just a regular grid with a variable number of rows & cols

Comment: @bidifx I will try to create a fiddle

Comment: of course but that involves the foreach, otherwise you can't declare to your zul it's about multiple objects

Comment: @bidifx here's a fiddle I finally managed to create:  http://www.zkfiddle.org/sample/25qpefb/3-Grid-with-template

Comment: @kelmer see my recent edit

Comment: @bidifx oh, you edited your answer. sorry, I saw it now.

Comment: @chillworld how would you do it with another grid based on my fiddle?

Comment: Just occupied about 50 minutes in your fiddle. Looks like that way doesn't work in MVC. I should go with the rowrenderer of @bidifx or change to MVVM (whitch is acually very simple way)

Comment: even in MVVM, I still find it difficult to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can use [forEach](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML_Reference/ZUML/Attributes/forEach) on your `<cell>${each.bList}</cell>`.

**Based on your comment:**
Another option would be a custom [RowRenderer](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Data/Grid#Live_Data) you can find more about it in ZK's [Grid](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Grid.html) and [RowRenderer](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/RowRenderer.html) Javadocs. As you are out for performance don't miss the part about `RowRendererExt.DETACH_ON_RENDER`.

Her is some sample code for you. It should give you a clou how to do it. Anyway performance can be improved.

**Set the `rowRenderer` for your grid:**

```
<grid id="myGrid" rowRenderer="@{base$composer.renderer}" model="@{base$composer.gridModel}">
```

**Add a getter to your composer:**

```
public RowRenderer<SingleRow> getRenderer() {
    return new RowRenderer<SingleRow>() {
        @Override
        public void render(Row row, SingleRow data, int index) throws Exception {
            new Label(data.getEmployee()).setParent(row);
            for (Activity activity : data.getActivities())
                new Label(activity.getName()).setParent(row);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: True, but experience has taught me -- that foreach implementation has an awful performance. It slowed down the rendering of my pages up to 5 seconds.

Comment: Based on your recent edits: this is the solution I have now. What I wanted to achieve is the same behavior but *declaratively*. The fiddle I posted was oversimplified but in actual truth I define events on each cell and also css properties based on its content. So I would rather do that declaratively on a `<template>` element if possible, instead of relying on Java code which causes high coupling.

Comment: Dude! How about stating that in the first place? :-/

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had :(